# convert binary data to gzip file and decompress to a string c#

Tags: c#, decode

I am trying to decode binary data that represents a gzip file, I need to decompress the gzip so I can get the nbt (minecraft notation thing) string that is in the gzip, but I keep getting the following error at GZipStream.Read:

> The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method.

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

This is my code:

```
public static string Decompress(string input)
{
    byte[] compressed = Convert.FromBase64String(input); //This is the binary data
    byte[] decompressed = Decompress(compressed);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressed);
}

private static byte[] Decompress(byte[] input)
{
    using (var source = new MemoryStream(input))
    {
        byte[] lengthBytes = new byte[4];
        source.Read(lengthBytes, 0, 4);

        var length = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBytes, 0);
        using (var decompressionStream = new GZipStream(source,
            CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            var result = new byte[length];
            decompressionStream.Read(result, 0, length); //Error
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you:

```
public static string Decompress(string value)
{
    byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
    byte[] decompressed;

    using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
    {
        using var outputStream = new MemoryStream();

        using (var gzip = new GZipStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress, leaveOpen: true))
        {
            gzip.CopyTo(outputStream);
        }

        decompressed = outputStream.ToArray();
    }

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressed);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it tomorrow. I got to get some sleep now D;